# How to add property to a prototype (javascript)

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to figure out how to make

```
normalFunction.prototype.helloWorld = 'hello world'

function normalFunction(){
 
}

function helloWorld() {
  return 'hello world'
}
```

For the problem `normalFunction` must be a function.

Answer (score 0):

Create your object

```
const normalFunctionPrototype = {
    helloWorld: () => 'hello world'
}
```

Create a new object with your first object as its prototype

```
let normalFunction = Object.create( normalFunctionPrototype );
```

We can now call its methods

```
console.log( normalFunction.helloWorld() ) // hello world
```